# Cannot find module node internal modules cjs loader:936

Tags: node.js, node-modules

❯ npm run callback

> asyncjs@1.0.0 callback
> node src/callback/index.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/milo2003/personalProjects/AsyncJS/src/callback/index.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install node version manager (nvm) before installing npm.
In my case, Nodejs was downloaded easily but npm was not getting installed.
After updating environment variable and system variable still its was showing cannot find module node internal module cjs loader: 936 when I tried installing npm (through npm install command).
I've checked through Youtube but couldn't resolve.
Then checked this doc : https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm

I got to know that to resolve my prob I should first install NVM(node version manager).
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm